# Word for "follow certain steps so that accidents do not happen"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, phrase-requests

I am trying to make the point that we must (form habit) follow certain steps to do certain things so that accidents do not happen.

For example, If I am moving something hot I must make a sound, look left and right or something like that every time whether someone is there or not, whether I feel it necessary or not. I can not skip doing it just because no one else is here today, or I feel there is no risk.

What would be the most appropriate word for it?

I came up with -

```
We must follow "Rules"
We must follow "Protocol"
We must follow "Instruction"
We must follow "Guideline"
We must follow "Best Practice"
We must follow "Standard"
```

But it does not sound right.

Comment: All of those ideas speak of a formalised laid-down procedure. Your preamble, however, suggests informality - "form habit to". It might help if you would tell us more about why you are writing this, and to whom it is addressed.

Comment: I am advising my family member in an informal setting.

Comment: What I am trying to say is `We must follow "Best Practice" to avoid remotely possible accidents` in a more generic term.

Comment: If I were talking to my intimate family, I certainly wouldn't use any of those expressions - they would sound quite pompous and inept. I would say something like: *When moving something hot it is a good idea to state loudly what you are about to do, and look around to ensure no one is in the way.* To insist on it being routine even if there is no one else in the house sounds a little like a case of OCD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Follow safe practices."

[Safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety) is the state of being "safe" (from French sauf), the condition of being protected from harm or other non-desirable outcomes.

[Safe Work Practices](https://www.ihsa.ca/resources/safe_practices_procedures.aspx)/Safe Job Procedures for addressing significant hazards

In plain language, meant literally, just

> [play (or play it) safe (or for safety)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/play)
>   Take precautions; avoid risks.
>   ‘I think we'll play safe and get another set of X-rays done’